# java: ActionListener variable contains action to modify itself - 'Variable might not have been initialized'

Tags: java, actionlistener, variable-initialization

I have a bit of code that does this:

1. Creates an ActionListener

   a. Removes itself from the button that it will be attached to (see 2.)

   b. Does some other stuff
2. Adds that ActionListener to a button

(in code:)

```
ActionListener playButtonActionListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        playButton.removeActionListener(playButtonActionListener);
        // does some other stuff
    }
};

playButton.addActionListener(playButtonActionListener);
```

On compilation, Java reports line 4 as an error `(variable playButtonActionListener might not have been initialized)` and refuses to compile.  This is probably because playButtonActionListener is not technically initialized completely until the closing bracket, and the `removeActionListener(playButtonActionListener)` needs to happen after playButtonActionListener is initialized.

Is there any way to fix this?  Do I have to completely change the way I am writing this block? Or is there some sort of `@` flag or another solution?

Comment: And yes, it **is** a duplicate, despite anything you posted (which I removed).

Comment: That is true; however it was not exactly a duplicate in the way that I expected the post to be marked.  I guess I did not search the listing hard enough.  Thank you.

Comment: Understand that it doesn't have to be an *exact* duplicate. The purpose of this site is not to give you an exact code solution, but to provide robust answers to general questions. The solution to "how do I access an anonymous object within the object itself" has already been well answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
playButton.removeActionListener(playButtonActionListener);
```

with:

```
playButton.removeActionListener(this);
```

Since you're in the ActionListener anonymous class, `this` represents the current instance of the class.

Comment: Thank you; I will accept this answer ASAP!

Answer (score 1):

The object you want to remove is the listener itself, so you can access it via `this`:

```
    ActionListener playButtonActionListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            playButton.removeActionListener(this);
            // does some other stuff
        }
    };

    playButton.addActionListener(playButtonActionListener);
```

Comment: Thank you; I will accept this answer ASAP!